# I want make some validation string that match the format below

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

I have a textbox, and I want to validate that it matches the pattern *Car Plate* = `[X]__[####]_[ZZZ]`.

- `[X]` = One upper case letter
- `_` = Space
- `[####]`  = Four digit number
- `[ZZZ]`   = Three upper case letter

Example : `A  1234 BCD`

How do I set validation to match this in a textbox?

this is my code according sir dimitri

```
private void isvalidplate(string a)
    {
        if (a[0] < 'A' && a[0] > 'Z')
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Car Plate is invalid!");
        }
        else if (a[1] != ' ' && a[5] != ' ')
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Car Plate is invalid!");
        }
        else if (a[2] != Int64.Parse(a) && a[3]!= Int64.Parse(a) && a[4]!= Int64.Parse(a) )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Car Plate is invalid!");
        }
        else if ((a[6] < 'A' && a[6] > 'Z')&&(a[7] < 'A' && a[7] > 'Z')&&(a[8] < 'A' && a[8] > 'Z')&&(a[9] < 'A' && a[9] > 'Z'))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Car Plate is invalid!");
        }
    }
```

but it show an error that "input String Was Not In A correct Format"
the error is in this line

```
else if (a[2] != Int64.Parse(a) && a[3]!= Int64.Parse(a) && a[4]!= Int64.Parse(a) )
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Use regular expresions, and the pattern: `[A-Z]{1} \d{4} [A-Z]{3}`

Answer (score 0):

A common tool used across many languages for string validation and parsing is Regular Expressions (often referred to as regex).  Getting used to using them is very handy as a developer.  A regex matching what you need looks like:

```
^[A-Z]\s\d{4}\s[A-Z]{3}$
```

[This site](http://regexr.com/3dd7s) shows your regex in action.  In C#, you could test your string using the `Regex` library:

```
bool valid = Regex.IsMatch(myTestString, @"^[A-Z]\s\d{4}\s[A-Z]{3}$");
```

There are tons of resources on learning regex online.

Comment: i'm forgot to mention before, my lecturer not allowed to use regex sir :(

Comment: Bah.  Then you'll have to show an effort if this is homework, rather than just asking for an answer.

Comment: Sp you have to implement an explicit test: `public static String IsCarPlateValid(String value) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return false; if (value.Length != 9)
        return false; ...  return true;}`

Comment: i try my best sir, but in this case i'm just get stuck sir, i try to use substring but it just return my string, and how to validate " one upercase" and other to specific string

Comment: @Andreas Gustavian: One *uppercase*: `(value[0] >= 'A' && value[0] <= 'Z')`, just direct comparison

Answer (score 0):

So you have to implement *explicit* tests:

```
public static String IsCarPlateValid(String value) {
  // we don't accept null or empty strings
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return false;

  // should contain exactly 11 characters
  //  letter{1}, space {2}, digit{4}, space{1}, letter{3}  
  //  1 + 2 + 4 + 1 + 3 == 11
  if (value.Length != 11)
    return false;

  // First character should be in ['A'..'Z'] range;
  // if it either less than 'A' or bigger than 'Z', car plate is wrong
  if ((value[0] < 'A') || (value[0] > 'Z'))
    return false;

  //TODO: it's your homework, implement the rest

  // All tests passed
  return true;
}
```

To *test* your implementation you can use regular expression:

```
Boolean isValid = Regex.IsMatch(carPlate, "^[A-Z]{1} {2}[0-9]{4} {1}[A-Z]{3}$");
```

with evident meaning: one letter, two spaces, four digits, one space, three letters.

Comment: i've edited my code sir, but it show an error when i try to parse the value into int, is my code going wrong sir?

Comment: @Andreas Gustavian: please, work with *char*s, not *int*s, e.g. to test if `value[3]` is *digit*: `if ((value[3] < '0') || (value[3] > '9')) MessageBox.Show("not a digit!");`

Comment: @Andreas Gustaviano: you're welcome! Now, you have to *implement* the routine; be careful with `&&` and `||`; another issue is with *loops*: long `if`s like `(a[6] < 'A' || a[6] > 'Z') || ... || (a[106] < 'A' || a[106] > 'Z')` look *ugly*; `for` loop is much better solution in the context.